# How to use kCATransitionPush type with CATransition from particular location in the view, not from extreme left?

Tags: xcode, animation, catransition

I am developing an application, which include some animations. Iam trying to get the effect of expand/collapse the view from a particular point (e.g. x=100, y=50) in the main view. Iam using CATransition with the type kCATransitionPush and subtype is kCATransitionFromLeft. But it is expanding from extreme left, but It has to expand from the particular point. what I need to do for that effect. I used the below code for that effect, Is there any alternative to implement the targeted animation.

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation.delegate = self;
animation.duration = 0.3f;  
animation.timingFunction = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut;
animation.type = kCATransitionPush;
animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
[[animatedView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"expand"];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

CATransition has startProgress  and endProgress property.

set these property! and read document